# Is there a way to send very complex queries in loopback using curl?

Tags: json, subquery, loopbackjs, strongloop, loopback4

I succeed when making simple queries in loopback, using curl, with fairly innocuous use of "or" and "and":

```
curl.exe  -s -o %TEMP%\output.json -X GET --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "Accept: application/json" --globoff  "https://somesite.com/data?filter={\"where\":{\"or\":[{\"id\":123},{\"id\":456}]}}&access_token=abcdefg123456"
```

But my need actually is to send a much larger number of possibilities for my ors and ands. I get to a point where the filter inevitably reaches some hard limit, that I don't have access to change at the server end, and I get a 414 Request-URI Too Large error.

Is there a way to specify larger filter queries via a file or any other way, in either Windows cmd or Git bash?

Thanks for your time,

Rip

Comment: The problem is not on the client but on the server side. If the server does not accept urls beyond a given length, you cannot send longer urls. Maybe the server can be configured to accept those filters as request body in a POST request?

Comment: thanks @derpirscher, I shall certainly ask

Comment: It looks like my prayers will be anwered, and some kind soul will implement accepting filters in  POST requests at the server's end.